# Querying child collections within a Ravendb document

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

Say I have a `blog` with a collection of `posts`, and each `post` has a collection of `comments`. I want to query all the comments to find the 5 most recent across all blog posts. With an RDBMS you simply go straight for the comments table, sort by date and take 5. Is it possible to do something similar within Ravendb, given that comments aren't the aggregate root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

highace,
Yes, you can certainly do that.
You can see how we do something similar here:
https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/RaccoonBlog.Web/Infrastructure/Indexes/PostComments_CreationDate.cs

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to store your comments as seperate documents rather than in each post otherwise you end up loading and saving the entire post document every time a comment is added.

With this in mind you would simply query your comments something like the following

```
session.Query<Comment>().OrderByDescending(x => x.CommentDate).Take(5)
```

Comment: I thought this would be the case. How do I link them to their parent post? - Give them a fake foreign key field and then perform another query based on that?

Comment: Not sure I can add much to the following article which explains the various options for creating document relationships, see if this helps http://daniellang.net/how-to-handle-relations-in-ravendb/

Probably adding a postId property to the comment and use the Include<T> would be the strategy I'd go for